# Send user to New Mailing page with Recepients Already Selected

Tags: civimail

We'd like to send admins to the New Mailing page (https://example.com/civicrm/mailing/send?reset=1) but have the Recipients field already populated with a specific Group. Is there a query parameter or a way to post to that URL with the recipients field set?

The idea is for us to create a Group and GroupContacts via the API (from an external web page), and then send the user directly to the Civi Mail page with that new group already selected for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the draft mailing url. If you are on the saved drafts page (`/civicrm/mailing/browse/unscheduled?reset=1&scheduled=false`). You can copy the link behind the continue button. It looks like this: `/civicrm/mailing/send?mid=1&continue=true&reset=1` So there is a mid parameter that points (i think) to a message id. If you open the link, it redirects you to the `/civicrm/a/#/mailing/1` page, where the last parameter seems a message id again. So if you know that id, you can construct a link that points to the mailing edit page. And if you are planning to setup the basics of the mailing with API, then it will returned to you in the API response.